# Looking for a jQuery plugin for automatic sizing and fitting of photos

Tags: jquery, photos

The project I'm working on collects photos from the web of many shapes and sizes. Some are landscape, some are portrait, and the ratio can of width to height can sometimes vary drastically. I need to be able to display these photos in a container (e.g. a gallery or solider) as nicely as possible. I was wondering if there is a jQuery plug-in out there that would help me do this. I do not necessarily need a slider or gallery, but rather a plug-in that will do its best to automatically zoom, resize and fit photos so they fit a container in the best way possible, without horizontal or vertical gaps. Has anyone heard of such a thing?

*EDIT*: I found a plug-in that almost does what I need, but it only seems to work on the background of the entire browser. I need more or less the same effect, but inside an arbitrary element.

http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty awesome plugin that fits images, content boxes, etc. into a defined area. If I understand your question correctly anyway I think this is along the lines of what you are looking for.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Can you point me to the specific Masonry element you're referring to? I checked the "images" element, but that just seems to arrange images on a page (if I understood it correctly).